# How to translate the models names showing in the rails_admin's panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to change how the models names showing in my rails_admin's panel, but I no figure out how to do it...

This is what I want to translate: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dISeN.png)
Note: the models names looks weird because I'm using this configuration is my `inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:es) do |inflect|
    inflect.plural /([^djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1s\2'
    inflect.plural /([djlnrs])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1es\2'
    inflect.plural /(.*)z([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1ces\2'

    inflect.singular /([^djlnrs])s([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
    inflect.singular /([djlnrs])es([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
    inflect.singular /(.*)ces([A-Z]|_|$)$/i, '\1z\2'
end
```

I have this in my `es.yml` (I'm using Mongoid instead of ActiveRecord):

```
mongoid:
    models:
      comment: "Comentarios"
      product: "Productos"
      quotation: "Cotizaciones"
      requisition: "Requisiciones"
      user: "Usuarios"
```

But it seems that it is not enough to change it in the rails_admin's panel

Comment: What is in your en.yml?  What is the default language?

Comment: In my en.yml there is nothing and my default language is `config.i18n.default_locale = :es`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Setting up :en is default
2. Changing the values in es.yml

However, you need to make sure that the admin's panel is using these files. In this case I suspect it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (sorry for the late response). As you suspect, it was the es.yml file that wasn't recognized by rails_admin. I fixed it, restarted my server and its works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use inside the rails_admin blocks the methods to directly specify the translations:

```
  rails_admin do
    navigation_label I18n.t('activerecord.models.office')
    label_plural     I18n.t('activerecord.models.offices')
  end
```

Its a workaround.